# Excel complicated count function

Tags: excel, count, countif

I have kind of a complicated count I can't seem to figure out.  Basically I have a table that looks similar to this image:

[image: Sample data]

Now what I need to do is:

1. Tally the number of 1's if the category = "Anon" in one cell, then count the number of 2's and 3's in separate cells all if the category = "Anon".
2. Wash/Rinse/Repeat for if it's "Watterson" and "Davis".

Is there any way I can count the occurrences of 1|2|3 and have it separated by category like this?

Sorry, kind of an Excel noob here.  I didn't think pivot tables would be correct though (especially because they want the dates to be columns, plus I couldn't figure out how to insert a conditional).  Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a pivot table with a computed column: *=count( iff(Value=1, 1 0) )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that you start from cell A1,

=SUMPRODUCT((list name to search for)*(value to search in the data area))

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6="Anon")*($C$2:$I$6=1))
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6="Anon")*($C$2:$I$6=2))
```

...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6="Watterson")*($C$2:$I$6=1))
```

...etc.

Comment: Man, thanks so much to the both of you.  I wish I had enough reputation to upvote these.  Or I guess I'm supposed to choose a correct answer?  I don't really see the option for that, but this community has been super kind and informative so far.  I award you with brownie points or schrute bucks if you prefer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that your screenshot shows cells A1:I6.

Then ...

- Add column headings "1", "2", "3" in cells J1:L1
- Put the formula `=COUNTIF($C2:$I2,J$1)` into J2 and copy it across and down
- Set up a list of unique Categories (Anon, Watterson etc) starting in A10
- Add headings in row 9 like "Category", "Tally of 1s", "Tally of 2s", "Tally of 3s"
- Put the formula `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$6,$A10,J$2:J$6)` into B10 and copy it across and down

My guess is that someone cleverer than I could construct a `sumproduct` formula for B10 that works without the need for the helper columns J:L.

[Edit] Using Maki's `sumproduct` formula in my structure, you can scrap helper values in cols J:I and put this into B10 -- `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6=$A10)*($C$2:$I$6=B$9))`

Comment: Man, thanks so much to the both of you.  I wish I had enough reputation to upvote these.  Or I guess I'm supposed to choose a correct answer?  I don't really see the option for that, but this community has been super kind and informative so far.  I award you with brownie points or schrute bucks if you prefer. :)